# Intercepting a add_action

Tags: plugins, hooks

Assume that some other plugin or theme uses a add_action hook. Is there a way to determine if a specific hook is being used by someone else?

Example: assume that a plugin has this code

```
add_action ( 'publish_post', 'myCustomFunction' );
function myCustomFunction() {
   // does something
}
```

Can my plugin 'look' for the use of that hook into 'publish_post'?  And can I remove that particular action hook before it fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`has_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_action/). It returns the priority of the hook if it exists, otherwise `false`. So check that the priority is not equal to `false` (and not just false-y, or being hooked at `0` will appear false) then use that to remove the hook.

```
$priority = has_action( 'publish_post', 'myCustomFunction' );

if ( $priority !== false ) {
    remove_action( 'publish_post', 'myCustomFunction', $priority );
}
```

There's also `has_filter()`, which does exactly the same thing (`has_action()` just calls `has_filter()`).

Comment: Sudden thought: is there then a way to tell where that action was defined (the source file that contains that do_action)?

Comment: I don't believe so. When adding hooks it's possible that the file with the `do_action()` hasn't even been loaded yet.

Comment: Looking for the file that contained the do_action, not the file that will process it. So if my_plugin.php contains a 'do_action', is there any way to log/determine that my_plugin.php was the 'culprit'?

Comment: Do you mean `add_action()`?

Comment: Whoops. Yes. Would be interesting to know what file has the add_action function, without having to scan all files.